# Astro transforming async generator functions is not supported yet

Tags: javascript, html, astrojs

I want to support old browsers for my website. I am currently trying to use `@vitejs/plugin-legacy`. But while building I get this error,

```
[vite:esbuild-transpile] Transform failed with 9 errors:
entry.mjs:551:0: ERROR: Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
entry.mjs:683:2: ERROR: Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
entry.mjs:696:0: ERROR: Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
entry.mjs:1256:2: ERROR: Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
entry.mjs:1295:0: ERROR: Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
...

Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
548|  function markHTMLBytes(bytes) {
549|    return new HTMLBytes(bytes);
550|  }
   |    ^
551|  async function* unescapeChunksAsync(iterable) {
   |  ^
552|    for await (const chunk of iterable) {

Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
681|      return "AstroComponent";
682|    }
683|    async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
   |    ^
684|      const { htmlParts, expressions } = this;
685|      for (let i = 0; i < htmlParts.length; i++) {

Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
693|  function isRenderTemplateResult(obj) {
694|    return typeof obj === "object" && !!obj[renderTemplateResultSym];
695|  }
   |    ^
696|  async function* renderAstroTemplateResult(component) {
   |  ^
697|    for await (const value of component) {

Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
1254|      return this.returnValue;
1255|    }
1256|    async *render() {
   |    ^
1257|      if (this.returnValue === void 0) {
1258|        await this.init();

Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
1292|    return typeof obj === "object" && !!obj[astroComponentInstanceSym];
1293|  }
1294|  
   |   ^
1295|  async function* renderChild(child) {
   |  ^
1296|    child = await child;

Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
1987|    }
1988|    if (!hydration) {
1989|      return async function* () {
   |             ^
1990|        if (slotInstructions) {
1991|          yield* slotInstructions;

Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
2029|      island.props["await-children"] = "";
2030|    }
2031|    async function* renderAll() {
   |    ^
2032|      if (slotInstructions) {
2033|        yield* slotInstructions;

Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
2086|    const children = item.children;
2087|    return index === all.findIndex((i) => JSON.stringify(i.props) === props && i.children == children);
2088|  };
   |     ^
2089|  async function* renderExtraHead(result, base) {
   |  ^
2090|    yield base;

Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
2111|    return renderAllHeadContent.bind(null, result);
2112|  }
2113|  const renderHead = createRenderHead;
   |                                       ^
2114|  async function* maybeRenderHead(result) {
   |  ^
2115|    if (result._metadata.hasRenderedHead) {

 error   Transforming async generator functions to the configured target environment ("chrome64", "edge79", "es2020", "firefox67", "safari11.1" + 2 overrides) is not supported yet
  File:
    entry.mjs
```

Reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ry3189

How do I fix this?

Comment: Any luck fixing this?

Comment: @totalhack You won't be able to fix this. Even if you succeed outputting legacy chunks, there is no way to tell astro inject legacy scripts in html files. https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/6096 and https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/5870

Answer (score 0):

Try running 'npm install' again, then run 'npm run build'
I always feel that it is because the initialization is not completed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).